Calculating correct longitude / latitude Polygon area using RGeo in Ruby on Rails
I try to calculate a fields polygon size using RGeo gem. Therefore i do:
require 'rgeo'
require 'rgeo/proj4'

factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
# factory = RGeo::Cartesian.factory(srid: 4326)
ring = factory.linear_ring(self.get_polygon.map { |lon, lat| factory.point(lon, lat) })
polygon = factory.polygon(ring)

polygon.area

With self.get_polygon is an array that looks like [[lon1,lat1], [lon2,lat2], [lon2,lat2], ...]. So it's longitude and latitude.
The error is:
Method RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPolygonImpl#area not defined.

When I use factory = RGeo::Cartesian.factory(srid: 4326) instead everything works fine but the area size in not correct.

I'm not sure I see a question here? The error is quite clear that RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPolygonImpl does not implement the method area, therefore you cannot construct this object and call area. The spherical_factory method documentation itself is also very clear on this: "Length calculations are available, but areas are not.". As for the Cartesian you will have to explain what "area size in not correct" means...

...Again referring to the documentation it states: "The actual implementation returned depends on which ruby interpreter is running and what libraries are available." but for reference here is the basic implementation
